# Visual C++ for Linux Development "Debugging->Program" and "Copy Sources->Additional sources to copy" improvements

Tags: linux, gcc, visual-c++, cmake, output

I am using VC++4LD and I have set everything to work, it works perfectly, I like the extension, but I have 2 places in the project settings that can be improved.

1st place is Debugging->Program, I have something like "$(RemoteProjectDir)/subfolder/another_subfolder/gcc.cmake/OUTPUTNAME" there and it works, but I want it to be in a more correct way. By default, there was "$(RemoteBuildOutputs)" and that was incorrect. I can't even figure out, what is stored in that string => I tried to echo it in Pre-Launch Command with both "echo $(RemoteBuildOutputs)" and "$(RemoteBuildOutputs)", but nothing was shown. The project is built with a script that jumps into the "/subfolder/another_subfolder/" first.
[image: Debugging->Program]
So how to find, what is stored in $(RemoteBuildOutputs) and how to set the Debugging->Program dynamically so I can reuse it in other projects?

2nd place is Sources->Additional sources to copy, there is a lot of "CMakeLists.txt" files in the project and all are added to the project via "Include In Project", but they aren't copied to the remote machine during the build, I fixed it by specifying all the separate "CMakeLists.txt" files in "Copy Sources->Additional sources to copy", but it was a hard work to list them all.
[image: Copy Sources->Additional sources to copy]
How to automatically copy all CMakeLists.txt to the remote machine without specifying them separately so I can again reuse it in other projects containing any CMakeLists.txt?

EDIT: 1 more thing => I include linux project into VS with "Show All Files", then I select all folders and remaining files outside of them and choose "Include In Project" from the context menu, but all CMakeLists.txt remain unincluded in project, how to solve it, so I don't have to go through all of them and include them 1 by 1?

Answer (score 1):

`$(RemoteProjectDir)` etc. are Visual Studio build macros that are expanded from pre-defined information like the project name and information entered into the project properties. They're not stored in environment variables. I don't know if there's a simple way to print the value of a macro but you can get VS to list the substitutions it makes by turning up the MSBuild verbosity : goto Tools/Options , `Projects and Solutions` / `Build and Run` page and set the `MSBuild project build logfile verbosity` to `diagnostic` (you probably want to use the log file 'cos it can spit out a lot of stuff).

As for CMake, various issues around it have been raised on the [VClinux GitHub site](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux) . That would be the place to ask for enhancements. You might also look at [VCLinux unoffical scripts](https://github.com/robotdad/vclinux) to see whether any of Marc's scripts can help you automate the project creation.

Comment: I will check the log with $(RemoteProjectDir) and check those scripts, but actual solution to my problems would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the Dropdown menu on that setting and click on `<Edit>`:

[image]

In the opening Window you'll see the expanded Macros:

[image]

Comment: Cool. And if you click on the `Macros` button (which is off the rhs of the second screenshot) it lists **all** the macros and their values. I hadn't noticed that before, thaks for the tip.

Comment: I knew it, but it works only for some Macros... Not for $(RemoteBuildOutputs).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles onto this because of the Edited supplemental question, I had the same problem in visual studio not adding every file after "Show all files" and hitting "Include in Project."  Certain files like "makefile.am" and configure scripts were not getting included and therefore, were not getting copied over to the Linux system during build.  My solution was to edit the .vcproj file and add a line that will include everything in a specified directory.  This can be done for a specific folder or recursively.

For instance, if I wanted to add everything in folder "A" I would add,

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="A\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If I wanted to add everything in folder "A" and well as all sub-folders and sub-folder contents,

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="A\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Care should be taken not to double included items.  Also, this should only apply to non-source items that will not be compiled.  Otherwise the "None" indicator should be appropriately changed (CLInclude for headers, CLCompile for c/cpp, etc).